# Laravel Upgrade issue from 5.2 to 5.7

Tags: laravel, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my laravel application from 5.2 to 5.7 version for that I edited my composer.json file and added this line:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5"
},
```

And I run composer update and I am getting this error :

```
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

My application is throwing errors:
(1/1) ErrorException
Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher $events) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot()

in EventServiceProvider.php line 8
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Declaration of App\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\\Contracts\\Events\\Dispatcher $events) should be compatible with Illuminate\\Foundation\\Support\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider::boot()', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kc/kyo-webservice/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php', 8, array('file' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kc/kyo-webservice/vendor/composer/../../app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php'))
in EventServiceProvider.php line 8
at include('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kc/kyo-webservice/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php')
in ClassLoader.php line 444
at Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kc/kyo-webservice/vendor/composer/../../app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php')
in ClassLoader.php line 322
at ClassLoader->loadClass('App\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider')
at spl_autoload_call('App\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider')
in ProviderRepository.php line 208
at ProviderRepository->createProvider('App\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider')
in ProviderRepository.php line 144
at ProviderRepository->compileManifest(array('Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Cookie\\CookieServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\FoundationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Hashing\\HashServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Pagination\\PaginationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Pipeline\\PipelineServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Redis\\RedisServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Auth\\Passwords\\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Session\\SessionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Translation\\TranslationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\View\\ViewServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Notifications\\NexmoChannelServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Notifications\\SlackChannelServiceProvider', 'Carbon\\Laravel\\ServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\AuthServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider'))
in ProviderRepository.php line 61
at ProviderRepository->load(array('Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Cookie\\CookieServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\FoundationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Hashing\\HashServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Pagination\\PaginationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Pipeline\\PipelineServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Redis\\RedisServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Auth\\Passwords\\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Session\\SessionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Translation\\TranslationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\View\\ViewServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Notifications\\NexmoChannelServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Notifications\\SlackChannelServiceProvider', 'Carbon\\Laravel\\ServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\AuthServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider'))
in Application.php line 550
at Application->registerConfiguredProviders()
in RegisterProviders.php line 17
at RegisterProviders->bootstrap(object(Application))
in Application.php line 204
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadEnvironmentVariables', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\BootProviders'))
in Kernel.php line 162
at Kernel->bootstrap()
in Kernel.php line 146
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php line 53
```

What is the process to upgrade my laravel application, in my case what should I do ?

Comment: check carefully there are lots of changes between 5.2 to 5.7 even folder structure is changed

Comment: It's a slow process, but you need to upgrade to 5.3 -> 5.4 -> 5.5 -> 5.6 -> 5.7 (in that order)

Comment: I am getting this error: Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

Comment: best way first update your app framework later upgrade all packages used in your project. or create new project with laravel 5.7 and than install packages at the end move your all models and controller to your new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find upgrade guides on the Laravel documentation. You need to upgrade one version at a time:

- [5.2 -> 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)
- [5.3 -> 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0)
- [5.4 -> 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade) (Additional step for 5.5 -> 5.5.42)
- [5.5 -> 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade) (Additional step for 5.6 -> 5.6.30)
- [5.6 -> 5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade#upgrade-5.7.0)

Also, you should probably clear the cache before upgrading:

1. Delete everything in `/bootstrap/cache/files`
2. Clear cache `php artisan cache:clear`
3. Clear view cache just in case `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: When I am trying to upgrade from 5.2 to 5.3 I am getting this error:   [ErrorException]
  Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher $events) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot()


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

Comment: @NilaySingh You need to remove the arguments from the `boot()` method in `EventServiceProvider`.

Comment: Now I am getting this error : Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources' not found

Comment: @NilaySingh Please follow the instructions in the links I have provided you. Everything is in there.